# Putting a loop inside of an if condition - can it be done?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I'm creating a tool that pulls in data from SQL and then extracts the data depending on dates and users relating to that data. I need this to work in a large range of users.

I have some code that currently has a nested for loop. Using `lastrow` variables, it checks to see if the value of a cell and the first loop value - for example `.range("b" & R)` - equals the value of a cell and the second loop value - `.range("H" & i)`. In this, there's an if statement e.g

If the date in `range("E"&r)` = the date in `range("G"&i)` and `lcase(range("A" & r) = lcase(range("H" & y) then...`

I need the value of  `y` to change to basically say `if G&i = H&y or H&y` and so on until it gets to the end of my range.

```
Sub mysub(sheet As String)

Dim i As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim hours As Single
Dim lastRow3 As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets(sheet).Activate

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = ActiveSheet.Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow3 = Sheets("mysheet").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 4 To lastRow2
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        For y = 2 To lastRow3
        If ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("AH" & r) And _
            LCase(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value) = LCase(Sheets("agents").Range("B" & y).Value) Then
            hours = hours + ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i).Value
        End If
        Next y
    Next i
ActiveSheet.Range("AE" & r).Value = hours
ActiveSheet.Range("AE" & r).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm"
hours = 0
Next r


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help on this would be a massive help.

Comment: This is only to answer the question from the subject... `Yes`... you can put a loop in an `if` condition.

Comment: That said I don't understand your question or how it relates to the title of the post

Comment: Looks like you're doing a SUMIFS in which case it would be easier to use `Application.SumIfs()` in your VBA

Comment: It's currently 2 levels and works. The question is around the 3rd level, being the variable y. I I want 'y' to change in the 'if' criteria as if to say if = b1 or b2 or b3 etc.

Comment: Tim Williams, thanks for giving a suggestion. I'll take a look at adding that!